# How to handle stdin, stdout with interactive threaded program?

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to automate router software upgrades using Python. I have a solution that works fine as a single threaded program. I'm trying to make it multi-threaded. My problem is that if there isn't enough space on the device to upload the software, it prints out the list of files on the device, and prompts the user to choose a file to delete. I'm trying to put that section of code under control of a lock but both of my threads print out the file list and prompt for user input as the same time.

```
class AsyncIOSupgrade(threading.Thread):

    # Queue of work
    work_queue = None
    # Event that will tell threads to exit
    stopper = None

    def __init__(self, work_queue, stopper):
        super().__init__()
        self.device_queue = work_queue
        self.id = threading.Thread.getName(self)
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.stopper = stopper

    def upgrade_ios(self, ip):
        # Do a bunch of stuff
        with self.lock:
            # build and print out menu of files
            # prompt user for input
```

The output ends up looking like this:

```
>>>> Starting upgrade for test-rt-01 on thread Thread-1
>>>> Starting upgrade for test-rt-02 on thread Thread-2
Insufficient space on remote device. Choose file to delete:
0   Don't delete any files
1   c2900-universalk9-mz.SPA.156-3.M0a.bin               106.73MB
2   vdsl.bin.32bdslfw                                    2.56MB
3   c2900-universalk9-mz.SPA.152-4.M5.bin                96.78MB    Insufficient space on remote device. Choose file to delete:
4   c3750e-universalk9-tar.150-2.SE7.tar                 25.08MB
5   credential.lic                                       0.0MB
6   2015-test-T2R2.txt                                   0.02MB
7   T1R2-withBB-2015.txt                            0.02MB
8   pingTest.tcl                                         0.0MB
9   pingTest__09-25-2015_01.54.33.txt                    0.0MB
10   pingTest__09-25-2015_02.19.50.txt                    0.0MB

Please choose an option: 0   Don't delete any files
1   c2900-universalk9-mz.SPA.156-3.M0a.bin               106.73MB
2   vdsl.bin.32bdslfw                                    2.56MB
3   credential.lic                                       0.0MB
4   c2900-universalk9-mz.SPA.152-4.M5.bin                96.78MB
5   c3750e-universalk9-tar.150-2.SE7.tar                 25.08MB
6   test.cfg                                             0.0MB
7   2015-test-T2R1.txt                                   0.02MB
8   T1R1-withBB-2015.txt                            0.02MB
9   music-on-hold-branch.au                              1.13MB
10   vstack                                               0.0MB
11   smartinstall_db.rev2                                 0.0MB
12   log.txt                                              0.0MB
```

Shouldn't one thread have the lock and print and prompt for input while the other thread waits for the lock?

Comment: Your threads have different locks. Only one thread will ever try to take each lock.

Comment: I moved the lock before __init__ and now it seems to be working. Thanks.

Comment: You need to create a `Lock` to control concurrent access to any shared resource, In this case it sounds like the terminal screen/stdout and the keyboard/user/stdin. Once you have those, you will need to acquire the lock before entering any section of the code that needs exclusive access to the item, and then release the lock afterward. In Python `Lock`s can be used as context managers which can simplify to just using a `with lock:` statement at the beginning of the section of code.